# How to insert DLL into project

Tags: c#, dll

It's my 3 day of working with C#, so my question is noobish, sorry.

I wrote small application, which works with `System.Web.Script.Serialization`, from `System.Web.Extensions` library. I have add reference to this *DLL* (it's from GAC).
But after installation of published application, it can not work on systems, where this *DLL* doesn't exist in GAC.

So I want to build this *DLL* into my application, to not depend on the existence of *DLL*.

What have I tried:

1. Added reference to *DLL* and turned option "**Copy Local**" to "**True**"
2. Copied *DLL* to the project folder and create reference to that file
3. In "**Prerequisites**" turned on option "**.NET 3.5 Framework SP1 Client Profile**"
4. In "**Prerequisites**" turned on option "**.NET 4 Framework Client Profile (x86 and x64)**"

And still I'm getting message `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`
When in my system application works fine.

Please, tell me, what should I do to compile application with this *DLL*.

System: Win7 x86, MS Visual C# 2010 Express (I have trial of professional, if it can help, but hope it can be solved in the Express edition too).

Comment: This is something regarding Private assembly think so

Comment: Change to .NET 4/3.5 profile(not client)...clean and build...close and reopen and try running.

Comment: Is .Net 4.0 installed on the client?

Comment: @Lily, "not client" asks for 2Gb, when application size is 12Kb. It's too much :)

Comment: @Tobsey Client Profile only. And it doesn't helps.

Comment: have you deployed your app with that dll?

Comment: @Reniuz yes, dll was in app's folder, but it looks like app can't see this dll. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. Will appreciate any link to comprehensive tutorial of publishing apps.

Comment: Please try the following: uninstall the DLL from your GAC and try running your app. What is the result obtained?

Comment: @AnilMathew can't remove, access denied. And it looks like special system folder, so Im' afraid to broke something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Web.Extensions` depends on `System.Web`, which is not part of the client profile, you should change your prerequisites

Comment: Thanks. How can I add reference to System.Web? Can't find this name in .NET tab, and in GAC too. I still hope my 12kb will not require 2Gb  Framework.

Comment: its part of the full framework, not the client profile. visual studio will filter it.

Comment: so it's impossible to compile application with this dll inside? My app will anyway require full framework to run?

Comment: i think that violates the license that microsoft gives you.

Comment: I just want my app be more compact, without any disassembling. I don't think it's violation of the license.

Comment: you should leave it to microsofts packaging. it would cause more problems than its worth.